# Setting a value of a text field from a 2D array depending on the option of a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a dropdown menu providing options for the USA states.

The array of the states is declared into the controller, in this form:

```
@us_states = [
      ['Alabama', 'AL'],
      ['Alaska', 'AK'],
      ['Arizona', 'AZ']
]
```

Now, I have another array (at the controller as well) that has a number for each state, in this form:

```
@electricity_table = [
        ['Alabama',0.078345],
        ['Alaska',0.1211736],
        ['Arizona',0.0773004]
]
```

With the `change` event, via jQuery, I can see with `alert` that the value of the dropdown menu for the states is the 2nd column (i.e. `AL`, `AK`).

Now I want to set the text_field with id `electr` depending on the State selected. 
That is, if 'AL' is selected, then as a jQuery:
`$('#electr').val(0.078345);`

How can I achieve this?

*I am new to Ruby on Rails and MVC, so please bear with me*

---

**Edit:**

This is the states dropdown code:

```
<%= f.input :var_state_oth, label: false, wrapper: :append do %>
<%= f.input_field :var_state_oth, collection: @states, class: 'answer-single', id: 'app_var_state_oth' %>
<% end %>
```

And this is the text_field that has to be set:

```
<%= f.input :electr, label: false, wrapper: :append do %>
<input class="answer-single" data-autonumeric="true" data-m-dec="0" id="electr" name="app[electr]" type="text" value="<%= @app.var_energy_cons_reduction %>">
```

And this is the jQuery code segment, that @adeneo proposed, with an alert added:

```
$('#var_state_oth').on('change', function()  {
  alert("change detected");
    var val = $('option:selected', this).text();
    $('#electr option').prop('selected', false).filter(function() {
         return $(this).text().indexOf(val) != -1
    }).prop('selected', true);
});
```

I don't even see the alert.

Comment: Your second array doesn't match the values you are using. Are you using the full state name in the text of the option ?

Comment: @adeneo: Yes in the text of the option I can see `Alabama`, `Arizona`, etc.

Comment: And it's the same in the second select, you see the full state name, but the numbers are the values.

Comment: Made a few changes below in the answer, see if you get an alert from that, and open your console to see if there are any errors etc.

Comment: @adeneo: I cannot see the answer :/ Have you accidentally deleted it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jsFiddle for one solution: http://jsfiddle.net/H6Sqh/1/

```
$('#var_state_oth').on('change', function () {
   var sel = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
    $('#electr').val(elec_rates[sel]);
});
```

You will need to get the Javascript variable `elec_rates` populated with data from `@electricity_table` like so in the view template assuming an erb template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%= var elec_rates = #{@electricity_table.to_json}; %>
</script>
```

Comment: The `change` event isn't caught with this jQuery code. I can only set the `onchange` function to call. With that in mind, how would the code be? (the `this` keyword is the one I am talking about).  Also, where in the `_form.html.erb` file should the latest code be added?

Comment: Have a seen the jsFiddle? Is that the behavior you are looking for? The code is working on the jsFiddle, you will need to tailor it for your code...

Comment: I;ve seen the jsFiddle, and I believe this is what I need. But, when adding the `<% var elec_rates = ${@electricity_table.to_json}; %>` at the `_form.html.erb` file I got this error `undefined method 'var'`.

Comment: Great, so if that is the desired behavior, you just need to wrap the js code in a script tag. See updated code in the answer above. Basically you need to bring the ruby instance var, @electricity_table into the js code so jQuery can use it. Cheers.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: `'${' is not allowed as a global variable name
/path/_form.html.erb:147: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input`. The array is declared into the `new` action of the controller.

Comment: So it looks like the @electricity_table var is not making it into the view erb? Make sure it exists by the the time the view is rendered.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51468/discussion-between-chris-and-devdude)

Comment: It should be loaded, as above the `electricity_table`, there is the `states` table, which is loaded fine. If you'd like we could move this discussion to the chat, [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51468/discussion-between-chris-and-devdude)